# Find intrinsic values of rows from row names?

Tags: r

I'm beginner in R and would like some help please.

I would like to find the value of row with the name of this row.

Imagine, if my data frame have 5 columns and 5 rows.
The columns names are : "345", 456", "4567", "3456", "349"
The row names are : "98","897","987","568","927"

How can I do for finding the column with the name "345" in a data frame/matrix and how I can I do for finding the row with the name "98" in a data frame/matrix ?

For exemple : the number of the column with the name "456" is 2 and the number of the row with the name "987" is 3.

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: Study `help("[")`.

Comment: The rownames must be unique. You cannot assign the same name "987" to two different rows .

Comment: Hello Roland, Thanks you but it doesn't help me or maybe I don't understand. I don't want the element in the box, I want the number of the row/column where is the element.

Comment: Yes Rhertel, my exemple is corrected. My rownames are unique in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which()`:

```
which(rownames(df1)=="987")
#[1] 3
which(colnames(df1)=="456")
#[1] 2
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100), 5, 5))
colnames(df1) <- c("345", "456", "4567", "3456", "349" )
rownames(df1) <- c("98","897","987","568","927")
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Rhertel !